# Is $\operatorname{Spin}(8)$ a direct product of $\operatorname{Spin}(7)$ and $S^7$?

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, manifolds

> Is $\textrm{Spin}(8)$ a direct product of $\textrm{Spin}(7)$ and $S^7$?

I met this statement in the literature, but without a reference. If it is true, where is it explicitly written?

Comment: $S^7$ is not a group, what do you mean by "direct product"?

Comment: Direct product as of topological spaces. Meaning that the bundle Spin(8) -> S^7 with the layer Spin(7) is trivial. Is it? I know a simple explicit formula for a local section of this bundle, but it is not global.
Sorry for  the sloppiness in terminology, I am a physicist ;)

Comment: I think this is true; Mimura says so, but I don't think he explains why.

Comment: Yes. This is true because $S^7$ is parallelizable.

Comment: Specifically: Regard $S^7$ as the unit octonions.  We have a map $L:S^7\to\mathrm{SO}(8)$ given by letting $L(u)$ satisfy $L(u)v = uv$ for $v$ an octonion.  For $g\in\mathrm{SO}(8)$, we have a smooth factorization $g = L\bigl(g(1)\bigr)\cdot \bigl( L\bigl(g(1)\bigr)^{-1} g\bigr)$, and the second factor clearly belongs to $\mathrm{SO}(7)$.  This establishes the diffeomorphism $\mathrm{SO}(8)\simeq S^7\times\mathrm{SO}(7)$.  Now pass to the double cover on both sides.

Comment: So it is a direct product of real analytic manifolds, just just topological spaces.

Comment: OK, thanks, I've got it! But do you know a proper reference (to put in the article ;) ) ?

Comment: Direct product of topological spaces, isn't it just "product"? "direct" refers to other group "semidirect" structures on the set-wise product, in the group context.

Comment: It's hard to find an explicit reference to something that is 'obvious, once you see it'.  The first place I would look would be Steenrod's *Topology of Fibre Bundles* (1951, or the second printing, 1957).  It might be in there.

Comment: <isn't it just "product" > OK, I will have it in mind :)

Comment: A "physically inspired" section that is not global is 
$\exp\{i \alpha_j \Gamma_j\}$ where $\alpha_j$ is a 7-vector with the length $\leq \pi$  and $\Gamma_j$ are $8\times 8$ matrices satisfying the Clifford algebra. It is not global because all $\alpha_j$ of length $\pi$ map to one single point g = -1 of Spin(7). Certain eight-dimensional instantons are related with this bundle. I will think whether the global embedding of $S^7$ that you've mentioned can be used to construct some other instantons.

Comment: Spin(8), not Spin(7) in the previous comment

Comment: Actually given a bundle $X\to B$ with fiber $F$, one can ask whether $X$ is homeomorphic to $B\times F$, and also whether the bundle is trivial. But in principle the second is stronger than the first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I suspected, the statement that the bundle $\mathrm{SO}(8)\to S^7$ is a product bundle, i.e., that
$$
\mathrm{SO}(8)\simeq S^7\times\mathrm{SO}(7)\tag1
$$
as bundles over $S^7$ is in N. Steenrod's [The topology of fibre bundles](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=AUCN&pg6=TI&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&review_format=html&s4=Steenrod%2C%20N%2A&s5=&s6=The%20topology%20of%20fibre%20bundles&s7=&s8=All&sort=Newest&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq&r=1&mx-pid=1688579) (as part of Theorem 8.6).

Note that Steenrod uses the notation $R_n$ for what is more commonly notated $\mathrm{SO}(n)$, these days.  (The '$R$' is for 'rotation group'.  He uses $O_n$ for the orthogonal group.)  His proof, based on the octonions (which he calls 'the Cayley numbers'), is exactly what I outlined in my comment above.  He does not give a reference to an earlier statement of the result, but refers to L. E. Dickson's famous *Linear Algebra* for the properties of the Cayley numbers that are used in the proof.

He does not discuss the spin groups, but, obviously, the equivalence of bundles
$$
\mathrm{Spin}(8)\simeq S^7\times\mathrm{Spin}(7)\tag2
$$
follows from (1) by passing to the respective double covers.

Comment: Thank you, Robert. I've posted a comment this morning, but it was not correct and I deleted it. I've understood the construction with octonion multiplication. However, octonions do not have a matrix representation - their multiplication is not associative.  I tried before to realize this bundle and find the section using the 8-dimensional matrix language. And this allows one to construct only local sections, but not a global one.

Comment: @AndreiSmilga:  A section of the bundle $\mathrm{SO}(8)\to S^7$ is given by $L:S^7\to \mathrm{SO}(8)$, where $L(u)$ is left-multiplication by $u\in S^7\subset\mathbb{O}$.  Giving an explicit section of $\mathrm{Spin}(8)\to S^7$ depends on having an explicit representation of $\mathrm{Spin}(8)$.  One such representation is as the group of matrices in $\mathrm{SO}(8)^3$ generated by $C(u) = \bigl(L(u),L(u){\circ}R(u),R(u)\bigr)$ for $u\in S^7$. Then $C:S^7\to\mathrm{Spin}(8)$ provides an explicit section of the spin bundle defined by $\mathrm{Spin}(8)\ni g = (g_1,g_2,g_3)\mapsto g_1(1)\in S^7$.

Answer (score 1):

Robert Bryant answered this question by interpreting an element of SO(8) as an octonion multiplication. But I've understood now (after exchanging messages with Robert) that there is a more direct construction.
Let $\Gamma_{j=1,\ldots,7}$ be antisymmetric purely imaginary $8 \times 8$ matrices that satisfy the Clifford algebra
$$ \Gamma_j \Gamma_k + \Gamma_k \Gamma_j = 2\delta_{jk} \,.$$
Then 28 mutually orthogonal Hermitian generators of SO(8) are $\Gamma_j$ and $\Sigma_{jk} = i \Gamma_j \Gamma_k$.
$\Sigma_{jk}$ are also the generators of Spin(7), and it is a bit more convenient to consider instead of $SO(8)$ the so-called Semispin(8) group (see e.g.  hep-th/9906059), which is isomorphic to $SO(8)$, but rotates spinors rather than vectors. Then any element of Semispin(8) can be represented as

$$
g_8 \ =\ \exp(i\alpha_j \Gamma_j) \exp(\beta_{kl} \Gamma_k \Gamma_l) \ =\ g_{S^7} g_7,
 $$
where $g_7$ is an element of Spin(7) and $g_{S^7}$ is an embedding of $S^7$ into Semispin(8)  if restricting $\|\alpha_j\| \leq \pi$.

This already looks as a direct product searched for and the only nuissance is that the representation above is not unique: $\mathbb{1}$ of Semispin(8) may be represented either as $\mathbb{1} \times \mathbb{1}$ or as $(-\mathbb{1})\times (-\mathbb{1})$. This nuissance disappears if one goes from Semispin(8) to its double cover Spin(8). The latter is represented by *two* distinct matrices
$\exp(i\alpha_j \Gamma_j) $ *and* $g_7$, and *this* representation is unique.